# create wiki pages in site pages library using powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-server, wiki-pages

Create Wiki Pages in site pages library using Power shell in sharepoint 2010. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

SharePoint SSOM comes with built-in method for creating wiki pages [SPUtility.CreateNewWikiPage method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.createnewwikipage(v=office.15).aspx), for example:

```
$WebUrl = "http://contoso.intranet.sp.dev/faq/"
$web = Get-SPWeb $WebUrl
$wikiPages = $web.Lists["Pages"]
$wikiPage = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility]::CreateNewWikiPage($wikiPages, [System.String]::Format("{0}/{1}", $wikiPages.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, "MyFAQ.aspx"));
```

but unfortunately it creates *non-editable* wiki pages due to inability to correctly specify page layout.

### How to create wiki page using SSOM in PowerShell

```
if ((Get-PSSnapin -Name Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null)
{
    Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
}

Function Create-WikiPage([string]$WebUrl,[string]$PageName,[string]$PageContent)
{
    $web = Get-SPWeb $WebUrl
    $wikiPages = $web.Lists["Pages"]
    $pSite = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingSite($web.Site) 
    $pageLayoutUrl = $web.Site.Url + "/_catalogs/masterpage/EnterpriseWiki.aspx"
    $pageLayout = $pSite.PageLayouts[$pageLayoutUrl]
    $pWeb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($web)
    $wikiPage = $pWeb.GetPublishingPages().Add($PageName, $pageLayout);
    $wikiPage.Title = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($PageName)
    $wikiItem = $wikiPage.ListItem
    $wikiItem["PublishingPageContent"] = $pageContent
    $wikiItem.Update()
}
```

Usage

```
Create-WikiPage -WebUrl "http://contoso.intranet.sp.dev/faq/" -PageName "FAQ.aspx" -PageContent "Welcome to FAQ"
```

---

### How to create a wiki page using CSOM in PowerShell

```
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll'

function CreateWikiPage()
{
param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$webUrl,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][System.Net.NetworkCredential]$credentials,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$pageName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$pageContent
    )
            $templateRedirectionPageMarkup = '<%@ Page Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.TemplateRedirectionPage,Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing,Version=14.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Reference VirtualPath="~TemplatePageUrl" %> <%@ Reference VirtualPath="~masterurl/custom.master" %>';

            $ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($webUrl)
            $ctx.Credentials = $credentials


            $wikiPages = $ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Pages")
            Invoke-LoadMethod -ClientObject $wikiPages
            $ctx.ExecuteQuery()


            $file = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileCreationInformation
            $file.Url = $pageName
            $file.Content = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($templateRedirectionPageMarkup)
            $file.Overwrite = $true


            $wikiFile = $wikiPages.RootFolder.Files.Add($file)
            Invoke-LoadMethod -ClientObject $wikiFile

            $wikiPage = $wikiFile.ListItemAllFields
            $wikiPage["PublishingPageContent"] = $pageContent
            $wikiPage["PublishingPageLayout"] = "/_catalogs/masterpage/EnterpriseWiki.aspx, Basic Page"
            $wikiPage.Update()
            $ctx.ExecuteQuery();

}
```

Usage

```
$credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential('username', 'password','domain')
$webUrl = 'http://contoso.intranet.com/knowledgebase/'
$pageName = 'MyFirstWikiPage.aspx'
$pageContent  = '<h1>Welcome to the Knowledge Base!</h1>'
CreateWikiPage $webUrl $credentials $pageName $pageContent
```

Please follow [this post](http://blog.vgrem.com/2013/11/19/some-tips-and-tricks-of-using-sharepoint-client-object-model-in-powershell/) for a more details.

Answer (score 2):

```
  $wiki = $web.GetList($web.Url.ToString() + "/SitePages")
  $rootFolder = $wiki.RootFolder;

  $wikipage = $rootFolder.Files.Add($rootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + 
 "/test.aspx", [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPTemplateFileType]::WikiPage)

  $wikiItem = $wikipage.Item;

  $wikiItem[[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBuiltInFieldId]::WikiField] = "Test";

  $wikiItem.UpdateOverwriteVersion();
```

Use $rootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl to get over "Value does not fall within the expected range" exception when adding wiki apge to site pages using powershell

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
 $listName="A"
  $siteURL="http://serverName:1111"
  $site=Get-SPSite $siteURL
  $web=$site.RootWeb
  $list=$web.Lists[$listName]                
  $rootFolder = $list.RootFolder
  $wikiPage = $rootFolder.Files.Add("/"+$rootFolder+"/Home.aspx", [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPTemplateFileType]::WikiPage)
  $wikiItem = $wikiPage.Item
  $wikiItem[[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBuiltInFieldId]::WikiField] = "Template Preview" 
  $wikiItem.UpdateOverwriteVersion()
```

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/4529/how-to-add-wiki-page-to-the-wiki-page-library-in-sharepoint.aspx

Comment: This is incorrect since wiki page will be created "non-editable", besides you could utilize SSOM  SPUtility.CreateNewWikiPage method

Comment: Exception calling "Add" with "2" argument(s): ""
At C:\sandeeptest\sales\Testwikipage.ps1:7 char:36
+   $wikiPage = $rootFolder.Files.Add <<<< ("/"+$rootFolder+"/Home.aspx", [Micr
osoft.SharePoint.SPTemplateFileType]::WikiPage)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Comment: i am getting above error.Please help.